# How to solve subset sum problem having large sum 10^18 with recurrance relation as array elements

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

Problem Statement

You are given N, the size of the array A and A0, the first element of the array. The other elements of the array can be calculated by:

- A[i] >= 3 * A[i-1] , if i is odd
- A[i] = 2 * A[i-1] + 3 * A[i-2] , if i is even

i varies from 1 to N - 1

The array follows a special propert. **The elements at even indices of the aray are even and elements at odd indices of the array are odd**. Your first task is to prepare this array such that the sum of the array is minimized, and array follows all the given conditions.
You are given Q queries. Each query consists of a single integer X. You have to print true if we can achieve it by adding some elements of the array A, false if it is not possible.

Constraints

- 1 <= T <=50
- 1<= N <= 5000
- 1<=A0<=10^6
- A0 is even
- 1<=Q<=1000
- 1<=X<=10^18

Sample Testcase

Input

```
1
4 2
5
3 27 36 68 88
```

Output

```
false
true
false
true
true
```

Explanation - Array elements are [2,7,20,61]

I have tried a naive and dp approach but received Memory Limit Exceeded.

Comment: Why are these the elements in the odd indices? I understand the even ones.

Comment: My intuition tells the way is to prove that each even element is greater than the sum of all even elements that came before, the same for odd elements. This way, for each query, you can DP on the lowest non-negative value you can achieve by choosing either the greatest odd element or the greatest even. Posting this as a comment because it may be very wrong :)

Comment: sorry guys.. replaced '*' with '+'. my bad. Thanks @arjun-singh for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A[i] >= 3*A[i-1] , if i is odd
```

Correction when i is odd it is multiplication not addition

Key Points:

1. There won't be much entries in the array upto 10^18 because every time we are multiplying by some number for next number
2. X is less than 10^18 so ignore numbers bigger than 10^18 in the array A, whenever first time overflow happens then stop calculating A[i]
3. A[i] is bigger than the sum of all elements at indexes less than i

   `A[i] > A[i-1]+A[i-2]......A[0]`

Now starting the solution 
For each Given X , K is size of the array A having numbers in increasing order where A[i]<=10^18

```
for(i=k;i>=0;i--)
{
    if(X>=A[i])
    X-=A[i];
}

if(X==0)
    cout<<"true\n";
else
    cout<<"false\n";
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the answer. I feel stupid after seeing the solution.
And all the best for future rounds (y).

Comment: Thanks bro there is a very small line between a solved and unsolved problem, so don't feel bad